# Key reference will not activate

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, key

Got an error in package-manager on an MVC 4 database connect - create on not having primary keys defined.

> error:  \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType
>   'Event_Class' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Found the `[Key]` to challenge the top element to be a key but no matter what I do, I cannot get this element of `[Key]` to reference.  It is simply black and not known by the compiler.  Am I missing a specific reference or using?

```
namespace eManager.Core
{
   public class Event_Class

    {
       [Key]
        public virtual int ClassID { get; set; }
        public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Compeditor> Type { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Current Using:

```
using eManager;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FluentAPI` In your `EdmEntity` class override [OnModelCreating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   builder.Entity<Event_Class>().HasKey(c => c.ClassID);
}
```

Then run your Migrations and update database.

Comment: Thanks.. I just got it.  Added the reference and using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; and it is now alive.  !